# SQL Syntax Error: Msg 156, 'Incorrect Syntax Near CREATE'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I can't find the Syntax Error in the following Query:

```
USE [Contact Manager]
GO
-- Define the Procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete_Contact]
    @contactID INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT OFF added enable Counting
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    -- Determine all Phone Numbers with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #PhoneNumbers (phone_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #PhoneNumbers (phone_number)
        SELECT phone_number
        FROM Contact_PhoneNumber
        WHERE phone_number IN
        (
            SELECT phone_number
            FROM Contact_PhoneNumber
            GROUP BY phone_number
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Declare Loop Variables
    DECLARE @i int = 0
    DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #PhoneNumbers)

    -- Delete all Phone Numbers with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
        EXEC sp_delete_PhoneNumber
        (
            SELECT phone_number, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY phone_number) AS row_num
            FROM #PhoneNumbers
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Addresses with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Addresses ([address] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Addresses ([address])
        SELECT [address]
        FROM Contact_Address
        WHERE [address] IN
        (
            SELECT [address]
            FROM Contact_Address
            GROUP BY [address]
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Addresses)

    -- Delete all Addresses with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
        EXEC sp_delete_Address
        (
            SELECT [address], ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY [address]) AS row_num
            FROM #Addresses
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Emails with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Emails (email INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Emails (email)
        SELECT email
        FROM Contact_Email
        WHERE email IN
        (
            SELECT email
            FROM Contact_Email
            GROUP BY email
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Emails)

    -- Delete all Emails with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
        EXEC sp_delete_Email
        (
            SELECT email, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY email) AS row_num
            FROM #Emails
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Groups with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Groups ([group] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Groups ([group])
        SELECT [group]
        FROM Member
        WHERE [group] IN
        (
            SELECT [group]
            FROM Member
            GROUP BY [group]
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Groups)

    -- Delete all Groups with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
        EXEC sp_delete_Group
        (
            SELECT [group], ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY [group]) AS row_num
            FROM #Emails
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

The comments should let you know what I'm trying to do, but I'm pretty certain that the logic behind the code is solid. I just don't know where the syntax errors are.

When I try to run the query to alter to stored procedure, I get the following errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_Contact, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_Contact, Line 113
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_Contact, Line 143
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
```

Comment: You seem to have several more ENDS than BEGINS.  I only see one BEGIN, and 3 or 4 ENDS.

Comment: This looks like it's missing the word "into", "INSERT #PhoneNumbers (phone_number)"

Comment: and one more suggestion not to use sp_ prefix for your stored procedure names as this is sql server's default naming convention for their procs and they advise users to not use it, I normally just use usp_Procname :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- Define the Procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_delete_Contact]
    @contactID INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT OFF added enable Counting
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    -- Determine all Phone Numbers with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #PhoneNumbers (phone_number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #PhoneNumbers (phone_number)
        SELECT phone_number
        FROM Contact_PhoneNumber
        WHERE phone_number IN
        (
            SELECT phone_number
            FROM Contact_PhoneNumber
            GROUP BY phone_number
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Declare Loop Variables
    DECLARE @i int = 0
    DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #PhoneNumbers)

    -- Delete all Phone Numbers with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
      BEGIN
        EXEC sp_delete_PhoneNumber
        (
            SELECT phone_number, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY phone_number) AS row_num
            FROM #PhoneNumbers
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Addresses with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Addresses ([address] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Addresses ([address])
        SELECT [address]
        FROM Contact_Address
        WHERE [address] IN
        (
            SELECT [address]
            FROM Contact_Address
            GROUP BY [address]
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Addresses)

    -- Delete all Addresses with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
     BEGIN
        EXEC sp_delete_Address
        (
            SELECT [address], ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY [address]) AS row_num
            FROM #Addresses
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Emails with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Emails (email INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Emails (email)
        SELECT email
        FROM Contact_Email
        WHERE email IN
        (
            SELECT email
            FROM Contact_Email
            GROUP BY email
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Emails)

    -- Delete all Emails with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
     BEGIN
        EXEC sp_delete_Email
        (
            SELECT email, ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY email) AS row_num
            FROM #Emails
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

    -- Determine all Groups with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    CREATE TABLE #Groups ([group] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

    INSERT #Groups ([group])
        SELECT [group]
        FROM Member
        WHERE [group] IN
        (
            SELECT [group]
            FROM Member
            GROUP BY [group]
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
        AND contact = @contactID

    -- Reset Loop Variables
    SET @i = 0
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Groups)

    -- Delete all Groups with a Single Link to the specified Contact
    WHILE @i < @count
     BEGIN
        EXEC sp_delete_Group
        (
            SELECT [group], ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (ORDER BY [group]) AS row_num
            FROM #Emails
            WHERE row_num = @i
        )

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
END
```

When executing More than One statement After While Condition you need to put them in  `BEGIN END` block

Answer (score 0):

And, I figured it out.

The example that I looked at for `WHILE` loops didn't mention that I needed a `BEGIN` to match the `END`.

So yeah:

```
WHILE (boolean)
BEGIN
    -- Do Stuff
END
```